# how do i make sure an empty string is really empty in PHP

Tags: php, string

Here's the issue I'm having:

```
if($id!="") return true; else return false;
```

I know that `$id` is an empty string, but when I do `var_dump($id)`, I get `string(25)""`

for some reason, though the string is empty, it still seems to think it's length is 25. I've tried `if(!empty($id))` and that also doesn't work.

How can I change the value of the string to be `string(0)""` if it really is blank?

I've tried using trim() to remove whitespace, but there isn't any whitespace.

Comment: What if you run it through `trim()` first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP allows for binary strings. The reason it's not showing as empty is because it *isn't* empty. Your string probably contains `\0` characters, or other unprintables or zero-size characters. You could try using `trim()`, but I can't guarantee that it'll strip strange characters out.

Answer (score 2):

It could be whitespace which isn't displayed by the browser.  Use [`trim()`](http://php.net/trim) to remove it:

```
$id = trim($id);
```

Comment: I figured out my own problem. When I echoed the string, I got nothing. But when I did a var_dump() on the string I found that there were 25 characters in the string. I did a foreach on the string's characters and var_dump on each character, I found that there was in fact data in the string. The result of the loop was `<? echo $some_variable; ?>`. PHP was evaluating the expression in the string to result in what looked like a blank string. But in reality, the string was a 25 character expression that evaluated to a blank string.

So...in this instance '' != ''

More than a little frustrating.